# Client rest Api not consuming method declared in server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jersey-client

I’m developing a signing app using rest jersey but I have an error in the client, it's not consuming the functions defined in the server app. I cannot find the problem.

**My controller:**

```java
@RequestMapping(value = { "/signpdf50" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Consumes({"text/plain,text/html"})
@Produces("application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<String>  signPDF5(@RequestBody String pdf) throws Exception {...}
```

The **test method:**

```java
public static Response signPDF50(String pdf1) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();

    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("sam", "sam");
    clientConfig.register(feature);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

    Entity<String> pdf= Entity.json(pdf1);

    Response response = client.target("http://localhost:8094/rubi/rest/signpdf50")
            .request("application/pdf")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(pdf);
    System.out.println(response.getLocation());
    return response;
}
```

When I call this method it always gives me **null** as a result, and nothing happens which means it's not consuming the method.
The string **pdf** is a byte array encoded to string before calling the method then decoded in the controller.

In the **controller**

```
@RestController
@ComponentScan
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class SigningControllerREst {
...
}
```

I tried System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));

```
<html><head><title>Login Page</title></head><body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3><form name='f' action='/rubi/login' method='POST'>
<table>
    <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
    <input name="_csrf" type="hidden" value="bbff729a-34e6-465c-a86b-0f521a927ccd" />
</table>
</form></body></html>
```

In **application.properties** I added these two lines for authentication

```
spring.security.user.name=sam
spring.security.user.password=sam
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: does your `signPDF5` controller method get hits when you request?
Moreoever, in your request uri  `rubi/rest/signpdf50`, is r`ubi/rest` the context path or you skipped unintentionally?

Comment: Can you add the complete response you receive ?

Comment: just **null** as a result when printing **response.getLocation()**

Comment: `accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` ?? Your endpoint does not @Produce json

Comment: I changed it to **.accept("application/pdf")** but the same

Comment: What is the actual HTTP response code? Should be available by calling `Response.getStatus()`.

Comment: The code is  200

Comment: If you're getting 200 then the URI path and the media types are correct. Can you update the question with the body of your controller method?

Comment: `response.getLocation()` is null therefore `response` is not. Location is only a tiny part of the entire response. So please add the **complete** response as I said in my previous comment.

Comment: @Consumes({"text/plain,text/html"}) VS. .request("application/pdf")

Comment: Here is the entire response **InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:8094/rubi/rest/signpdf50, status=200, reason=OK}}** but nothing happens with the method itself.

Comment: What does `response.getEntity()` return? Have you tried calling your end point with curl or postman to see if you get the expected response?